# Regex Universal URL Validation

Tags: regex, url

I wanted to validate all types of URLs using Regex like,

```
https://
http://
ftp://
magnet:
```

which I can do individually for each type. But I want to know how many different types of URLs are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IANA maintains a registry of officially registered URI schemes.

https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml

This is obviously a moving target; your program will need to have an up to date copy of this information at any time (and of course there will always be informal schema types which are not approved; for example, `s3` does not seem to be on the list).

Answer (score -1):

for magnet links:

```
/magnet:\?xt=urn:[a-z0-9]+:[a-z0-9].+/i
```

for other http links:

```
/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/gm
```

Comment: I wanted to explore all the possible URLs. As from my question: "But I want to know how many different types of URLs are there?" I don't need these expressions. Should have the read the question first :/